# triangle formulation

Tags: geometry

I have an right triangle with base 1, height 1 and the hypotenuse a 45 degree line from the origin. The point at 1/sqrt(2)  divides the triangle into 2 equal ares as shown below

lower triangle

$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot a\cdot a=\frac{a^{2}}{2}.
$$

upper trapezoid

$$
\frac{1+a}{2}\cdot (1-a)=\frac{1-a^{2}}{2}.
$$

setting them equal give a = ~.7

How would this change if lets say you had 10,000 points populate this triangle but the location of each point is determined using a t distribution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If corresponding sides in two *similar* triangles have ratio $\lambda$, the ratio between the areas of the triangles is $\lambda^2$. Which triangles are clearly similar, when figure $(2)$ is cut with a horizontal line?

Answer (score 2):

For the second triangle, let $a$ be the point on the $y$-axis that splits the area in two.

Then, the lower figure is a triangle with area:

$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot a\cdot a=\frac{a^{2}}{2}.
$$

and the upper figure is a trapezoid and its area area is:

$$
\frac{1+a}{2}\cdot (1-a)=\frac{1-a^{2}}{2}.
$$

Since these areas must be equal, we have

$$
\frac{a^{2}}{2}=\frac{1-a^{2}}{2}\implies a^{2}=1-a^{2}\implies 2a^{2}=1\implies a^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\implies a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$